# How to give a specific pattern to a textbox in windows form C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working in a c# windows form application and I need to have the below explained pattern in a textbox.

First: Numeric value (0123456789)

Second: One of arithmetic - multiply, plus, minus, or divide (+*-/)

Third: Decimal number (.)

Below are the examples

1234567890*17.325
or

1234567890+17.325
or

1234567890-17.325
or

1234567890/17.325

It should allow to type only numbers and arithmetic in the textbox and should not repeat arithmetic and decimal point.

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce your question to one specific problem rather than "can someone written my calculator app for me? Here is the spec". SO is a help service, not a gratis freelance service

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. This is a very small part of my program which I am trying to solve for some time. Thought writing both matters together would be good rather than writing 2 separate questions. I am new to stack overflow and hope I haven’t violated any of its rules.

Answer (score 1):

1. for Numeric values it would be better to use maskedTextBox instead of TextBox.
2. in maskedTextBox events like MaskChanged event write your required logic, these events will handle the execution for you.

Comment: Masked TB probably not great because of the relative inflexibility of the mask compared to the input requirement but I'd be keen to see a suggestion of what mask you'd recommend and some indication of how it would end up working